# Black plot in matplotlib.pyplot on jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook on mac and try to test matplotlib.pyplot but 
am getting a black plot. I would be appreciated if you can help me out to
resolve the problem.

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,5,50)
y_cos = np.cos(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y_cos)
plt.show()
```

the following link shows a black plot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/60PgN.png

Comment: I can only confirm that the code should work fine. Matplotlib can work with many kinds of backends for visualization: is it possible that none are installed, or a missing one is being used? You can `import matplotlib; matplotlib.get_backend()` to see which backend is in use.